# How to collect kernel panic system crash reports?

Tags: 11.04, kernel

How can I collect kernel panic crash reports. I have a relatively new *Asus X53E* system running 11.04. I am experiencing system crashes regularly with caps lock light flashing and kernel panic screen but I do not know how to collect crash reports so as to report them. I do have a picture of it but do not know how to attach in these case

Comment: To add a picture, you can edit the question and click in the button that says `img` above the edit box.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).